# Saving image from WMS service

Tags: r

When I open the following link in my broser, I can see the resulting image in the browser: 
[https://www.umweltkarten.mv-regierung.de/script/mv_a3_wasserschutz_wms.php?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&format=image/png&VERSION=1.3.0&layers=t3_wsg&crs=EPSG:4326&bbox=53,11,55,12&width=2048&height=2048]:

[(see this Screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3fSF.png)

When using this url to download the file, a file is generated (also its file size is plausible) but it is not a proper png-file. IrfanView throws a Decode error (Invalid or unsupported PNG file).

```
url <- "https://www.umweltkarten.mv-regierung.de/script/mv_a3_wasserschutz_wms.php?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&format=image/png&VERSION=1.3.0&layers=t3_wsg&crs=EPSG:4326&bbox=53,11,55,12&width=2048&height=2048"
Filename <- "C:/tmp/xxx.png"
download.file(url=url, destfile=Filename)
```

To get this png, the command download.file() seems to be the wrong choice. Can anyone help?

Comment: just gave this a try, and actually I can correctly open the downloaded png file. Perhaps try to open it with some other software? Even with the browser itself?

Comment: When I copy the url and paste it in a browser (edge or firefox) I get the image in the browser. But when I run the three lines of code, I don't get a proper file. (I tried several image editors).